# Are the massive spinors (left and right Weyl spinors) helicity eigenstates?

Tags: mass, dirac-equation, spinors, helicity

For massless spinor, with the help of Dirac equation, I can show that both left-handed and right-handed Weyl spinors are helicity eigenstates with eigenvalues +1 and -1 (respectively). I am unsure about how to proceed for massive Weyl spinors.

Comment: Is't "massive Weyl spinor" a self-contradiction?  Or perhaps you mean massive Dirac spinors in the helicity basis?